# Remove all special characters except space

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to remove all special characters from a range. I've got it to maintain only numbers and letters, but it also removes spaces. Since The strings have more than one word, it's supposed to retain spaces. It should maintain alphanumeric + space.

What I've got until now:

```
Sub RemoveNotAlphasNotNum()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Range"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    xOut = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(Rng.Value)
        xTemp = Mid(Rng.Value, i, 1)
        If xTemp Like "[a-z.]" Or xTemp Like "[A-Z.]" Or xTemp Like "[0-9.]" Or xTemp Like "[\s]" Then
            xStr = xTemp
        Else
            xStr = ""
        End If
        xOut = xOut & xStr
    Next i
    Rng.Value = xOut
Next
End Sub
```

It seems I can't figure out the space code to maintain.

Comment: perhaps [vba regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) will be more straightforward, or you can add `Or xTemp = " "`

Comment: it seems it works, but I noticed that my code doesn't remove dots also (.). Tried with "." too... But nothing. any suggestion?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't want dots then don't include them in the allowed character classes, eg

```
If xTemp Like "[a-z]"
```

rather than

```
If xTemp Like "[a-z.]"
```

( `"[0-9]"` will not preserve decimal points in numbers.)

Answer (score 1):

## Remove Non Alpha Numerics incl. SPACE

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveNotAlphasNotNum()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim xTitleId As String
    Dim xOut As String
    Dim xTemp As String
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim i As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "Range"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        xOut = ""
        For i = 1 To Len(Rng.Value)
            xTemp = Mid(Rng.Value, i, 1)
            If xTemp Like "[ 0-9A-Za-z]" Then
                xStr = xTemp
              Else
                xStr = ""
            End If
            xOut = xOut & xStr
        Next i
        Rng.Value = xOut
    Next

End Sub
```